# How to read everything inside the Quotes of an XML file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have some xml and I am not sure how to get everything that is inside the quotes.  I would like to get everything such as "First Text" and "Second Text" and so on. My goal is to put all of that into a output file.  I understand how to load the document and write it to a file but I am not sure exactly how to grab everything inside the quotes so I can actually put it into the file.  I am using Linq to XML in c#. Any help is appreciated thank you!

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="First Text" Margin="5"/>
            <Label Content="Second Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="Third Text"/>
            <GroupBox Header="Fourth Text">
                Fifth Text
                that extends to another line.
            </GroupBox>
            <Button Content="Sixth Text"/>
            <Frame Content="&lt;Seventh Text&gt;"></Frame>
            <ComboBox>
                Eighth Text</ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is what I have so far, I am aware that it wouldn't really work but I have no clue where to go with it or what to change.  I am pretty sure that the doc.Descendants("text") is what is wrong here.  Thank you

```
public void readFile(XDocument doc)
    {
        var item = from r in doc.Descendants("text")
                   select new
                   {
                       Text = r.Element("text").Value
                   };
        foreach (var r in item)
            WriteLine(r.Text);
}
```

I have also tried this method.  Which does not seem to be working either.  It is not LINQ to XML but instead it is using a XmlTextReader.  I am also not sure what is considered better than the other.  the Xmltextreader seems a little easier to understand syntax wise, but LINQ to xml is quicker(I believe).  I could be wrong about that though.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
        if (reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            WriteLine(reader.Name + " Attribute");
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.AttributeCount; i++)
            {
                readerXML.MoveToAttribute(i);
                WriteLine("Name: " + reader.Name + ", Value: " + reader.Value);
            }
        }
        reader.MoveToElement();
        }
```

Comment: You state that you're using LINQ to XML, so post what you've tried.

Comment: I edited the post, sorry for not including that in the first place.  WriteLine just creates a streamwriter and appends to a file.  But in the mean time I am just struggling on actually getting what I want.  Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the values for the attributes in the XAML file?  Do you want just a list of those values, or do you need them in a collection of some sort of object?  Do you need every attribute's value, or just certain ones?

Comment: I only need a list of those values.  I am trying to just output them into a file so I can know everything inside of the quotes for any xml file that I want.  I need every value that is inside quotations.

Answer (score 0):

those text items are called attributes and there is a class called `get_attributes` you can use. please post some of your code so i can show you where to insert.

Comment: I have posted what I have so far(not much) but thank you